# Error due to OLE DB specification

Tags: ms-access, vba, connection

I have this macro which was running perfectly fine for over a month.

I added an other module with the same exact connection, it doesn't work anymore neither in that new module nor in the previous ones which were running fine.

The error is :

[image]

and pops up on `conn.Open`

Here it this part of the code :

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim connStr As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & "'P:\intranet_path\" & "NewVersion.accdb" & ";"
conn.ConnectionString = connStr
conn.Open
```

Any ideas how to fix this and why it was working fine only for a while ?

Comment: You haven't closed the ' s in the file path, not sure that you need them

Comment: Yeah you're right ! My bad. It's weird that it was working fine for a month though. That mistake was there too. Thanks !

Comment: I removed it and it works fine